# MonoTouch.Dialog using events on arbitrary element to navigate back

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

How can I navigate back with events (let say Tapped for String element)?
Programmatically

```
Section s =  someelement.Parent as Section;
RootElement re =  s.Parent as RootElement;
// how to get to DialogViewControler or something to navigate back?
```

Thanks

mel

Answer (score 0):

Pretty new here but don't you want to use the `NavigationController` to do that?
I guess you're inside a `DialogViewController` where your event's implemented? 
So you could just do :

```
this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Baramuse's answer will work IF your DVC is within a NavController. But MTD works in both a nav controller style and modal dialog style. Your better off letting MTD do that work for you (so if anything changes in the future your code will still work). [The `DialogViewController` provides just the method](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/DialogViewController.cs):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Dismisses the view controller.   It either pops or dismisses
    /// based on the kind of container we are hosted in.
    /// </summary>
    public void DeactivateController (bool animated)
    {
        var parent = ParentViewController;
        var nav = parent as UINavigationController;

        if (nav != null)
            nav.PopViewControllerAnimated (animated);
        else
            DismissModalViewControllerAnimated (animated);
    }
```